# Retrieve the list of events from Google Calendar API of a domain with super administrator Google G suite account

Tags: google-calendar-api

Using Google Calendar API:

- I succeed to retrieve the list of events from a single google account.
- However, I can't do that within a domain (for example entreprise.tn) that have many users accounts even using a super administrator Google Suite account.

Could you please tell me what I missed ?.
Big Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to that thread https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

HTH.